# Why is it "to complete" rather than "to be completed" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Given that "complete" is a transitive verb meaning "to finish doing or making something," why is it "to complete" rather than "to be completed" in the following example from a dictionary?

"The building took two years to complete."

Comment: It's usually a ***To Do*** list, not ***To Be Done***, but ***TBA = To Be Announced***, not ***To Announce***. Go figure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['took several years to be built' or 'took several years to build' –  which one is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414475/to-be-built-or-to-build-which-one-correct)

Comment: Both are valid.  "To be completed" distances the builder to a degree, and might be more appropriate where the building (or perhaps pyramid or aqueduct) went through several owners/builders in the process.